# how to read the channel uri from toastnotification event in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows phone application and I could send a message to another windows phone device based on that device's channel uri.

```
 public static HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
 App.pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);
 App.pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
 void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
  {
   //TODO:
  }
```

I have below questions related to the above code:

1. How do I read the channelUri of the sender so that I can reply to the sender ? I see it is available in sender -> ChannelUri- > AbsoluteUri
2. And if sender wants to send more parameters can we add more toast xml tags apart from wp:Text1 and wp:Text2 or do we need to make use of wp:param only?
3. In scenario like Chat application should my code first store the channeluri of every device in some database and then when it wants to send a message to a particular user/device, it should read that particular user's channeluri based on his id or emailid ? Any other suggestion in this point on how to maintain users info for exchanging the messages ?

Answer (score 2):

1.
You don't get the channel Uri, because they are not build for direct device to device communication. You have to transmit them by yourself.

2.
In a toast notification you only have these params available.

3.
Your application probably won't work without an extra server that manages the device/user/channel ids. Push Notifications are not made for direct device to device communication.

ChannelUris may change at any time, so your app has to send it to your server from time to time (recommended is on every start).

Also, notifications have a very limited payload, so you need to transfer the complete messages and user data on another way.